# has_many :condition multiple models how to use join here?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, associations

I have the following model structure:

Model Visitor

```
class Visitor < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many: triggers 
end
```

Model Trigger

```
class Trigger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :visitor, :inverse_of => :triggers
  belongs_to :event, :inverse_of => :triggers
end
```

Model Event

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many: triggers 
end
```

I am trying to setup a custom association in Visitor model like so:

```
has_many: triggers_that_pass_some_condition ,:class_name => "Trigger", 
 :conditions => ["triggers.some_column >= events.some_column"]
```

The problem is that it doesn't work .. I am guessing I have to do some kind of join to compare columns of two separate models (that are associated with each other)

I have tried 
triggers.some_column >= triggers.event.some_column

That does not work either. Anyone has any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the clue from Darpa, I eventually settled on this:

```
 has_many :custom_trigger, {:class_name => "Trigger", :include => :event,
 :conditions => ["triggers.some_column >= events.another_column"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you first add the correct association between `Visitor` and `Trigger` in your model setup. From there, you can add a custom association as follows:

```
class Visitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :approved_triggers, -> { includes(:events).where("events.something = ?", true).references(:events) }, class_name: 'Trigger', inverse_of: :visitor
end

class Trigger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :visitor, inverse_of :triggers
end
```

Right now your `Trigger` class holds no association to a `Visitor`.

Comment: You are right, I did not show the association between trigger and visitor. I had it in my code. I edited my question: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code..

```
class Trigger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event 
  belongs_to :visitor
end

# Visitors.rb
has_many :triggers_with_condition, -> { includes(:event).where(some_trigger_column >= event.some_event_column)}, class_name: "Trigger"
```

Comment: I will try this and see how it goes, thanks for the reply.